# Powershell - Regular Expression

Tags: regex, powershell, find

I'm trying to retrieve a string from within a file that exists between two strings for which I'm using the regular expression below... And it works!

```
$Content = Get-Content $File
$Regex = [regex] "(?is)(?<=\b$String\b).*?(?=\b$String\b)"
$Matches = $Regex.Matches($Content)
```

But I have an issue. The actual string I'm looking for is set by the user and varies in size, from one to twenty-four characters. If it is at the maximum, it is no longer separated '$String' by white space, and hence becomes part of that string and so I think that is the problem with not being able to find it. Now bear with me and I'll explain the format of what I'm looking for... It goes...

```
$Name[Ten White Spaces]$StartOfStringImLookingFor[If string reaches 24 characters then 'no' white space]$Name
```

So if the issue is in the regular expression not being able to perform its function when `$StartOfStringImLookingFor` reaches `$Name`, then the ideal situation would be to...

Find `$Name` and return the next 34 characters, but is this possible? I don't how to do this and a search did not return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find $Name and return the next 34 characters:

```
$regex = "$([regex]::Escape($Name))(.{34})"
[regex]::Matches($Content,$regex) |
foreach {$_.groups[1].value}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! How would I get the 34 characters after the first match only into a variable? Sorry, my level is basic and I've tried but haven't been successful. I will then be outputting this variable to a file. Edit - Sorry, did it. Thanks for your help!